# UK tourist visa: should I add my residence countries to the visited ones?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I am applying for UK tourist visa and there is a question about visited countries within the past 10 years. The thing is during the past 10 years I lived in 2 foreign countries as a temporary resident with work permit. Should I add these countries? For example, country: Slovakia. Entry date: Dec 21. Leaving date: May 2023. Reason: work. Is it ok? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should include them.

The ECO will be looking for positive indications that you intend to comply with UK Immigration rules. Evidence that you have previously complied with other countries’ rules will help with that.

Source: [Travel/immigration history](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1167576/Visit.pdf#page21)

You should of course ensure that your application demonstrates that you do not intend to work while in the UK, for example that you have a job back home to return to after the proposed visit.